# pwntcha build error in Cygwin: undefined reference to imlib_load_image

Tags: cygwin, build-error

I'm trying to build [pwntcha](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/PWNtcha) on windows using Cygwin with imlib2. At the "make" step I get the error message:
/home/username/pwntcha/src/image.c:37: undefined reference to imlib_load_image.
Can anyone help me to solve it?

For more detailed:

```
gcc `imlib2-config --cflags` -DX_DISPLAY_MISSING=1 -Wall -O6 -g -O2 `imlib2-config --libs`   -o pwntcha.exe pwntcha-main.o pwntcha-filter.o  pwntcha-font.o pwntcha-image.o  pwntcha-easter-eggs.o pwntcha-test.o authimage/libdecoder.a clubic/libdecoder.a java/libdecoder.a linuxfr/libdecoder.a livejournal/libdecoder.a lmt/libdecoder.a paypal/libdecoder.a phpbb/libdecoder.a scode/libdecoder.a slashdot/libdecoder.a ticketmaster/libdecoder.a tickets/libdecoder.a vbulletin/libdecoder.a xanga/libdecoder.a
pwntcha-image.o: In function `image_load':
/home/username/pwntcha/src/image.c:37: undefined reference to "imlib_load_image"
/home/username/pwntcha/src/image.c:63: undefined reference to "imlib_context_set_image"
/home/username/pwntcha/src/image.c:64: undefined reference to "imlib_image_get_width"
/home/username/pwntcha/src/image.c:65: undefined reference to "imlib_image_get_height"
    /home/username/pwntcha/src/image.c:66: undefined reference to "imlib_image_get_width"
```

/home/username/pwntcha/src/image.c:68: undefined reference to "imlib_image_get_data"

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`gcc` resolves symbols in the order listed.  You need to patch the build system to move `` `imlib2-config --libs` `` to the very end of the link command.